# Swift - Pass generic C functions as address without specifying it's signature

Tags: swift

I have a C function which I want to pass it's address to another function.

For this I'm able to do the following:

```swift
let fn: @convention(c) (_ query: CFDictionary, _ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>?) -> OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching
let addr = unsafeBitCast(fn, to: UInt64.self)
```

This does work, but I want to be able to do the same thing without having to specify the entire function signature every time.

The reason for this is that I want to create a function that receives a (any) C function as a parameter, and does this conversion for me.

Is there any existing way to do this?

Something like:

```swift
func convertToInt(_ fn: AnyCFunction) -> UInt64 {
    return unsafeBitCast(fn, to: UInt64.self)
}

let addr = convertToInt(SecItemCopyMatching)
```

Comment: More context might be helpful. If you have the address of “some C function” as an integer, how would that be used?

Comment: @MartinR I'm eventually passing this function pointer to my C code and use it there.